# Looping a function with callback and wait for result

Tags: javascript, node.js

I understand the basic concept  of await, async and Promises. I tried alot of them but couldn't get the expected Result. For that reason, i ask you guys for help. Thx in advance.

I kicked all unnecessary lines of code, that you can see quickly what i want to do.

```
app.post('/create',  (req,res) => {

  var dataArray = [] 

  req.body.array.forEach((ele) => {

  let blobAdress = ele.link.split('/')[0];
  let extracted = ele.extracted
  let blob = `${blobAdress}/extracted-${extracted}.json`;
  const container =  'test';

  //SHOULD BE EXECUTED FOR EACH ELEMENT OF FOR LOOP  
 
  api.getTextFromBlob(container, blob,  (response, error) => {
   if (error){console.log("Error",error)}
     let jsonResponse = JSON.parse(response);
     console.log(jsonResponse)
     dataArray.push(jsonResponse) // I WANT ALL DATA FROM THE CB IN ONE ARRAY BUNDLED
     })
  })

// RUN THIS PART AFTER FOR LOOP HAS BEEN EXECUTED PROPER

console.log(dataArray) // !ASYNC JS --> DATA ARRAY IS EMPTY BECAUSE datArray IS CONSOLE.LOG BEFORE api.getText EXECTUED
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap you callback function into [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/Promise) object first:

```js
var getTextFromBlobAsPromise = (container, blob) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    api.getTextFromBlob(container, blob, (response, error) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log("Error", error)
            return reject(error); // depends on business
        }
        let jsonResponse = JSON.parse(response);
        console.log(jsonResponse)
        resolve(jsonResponse);
    })
})
```

Then you can await until all promises will resolve using [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) function:

```js
app.post('/create', (req, res) => {

    var promises = [];
    req.body.array.forEach((ele) => {
        let blobAdress = ele.link.split('/')[0];
        let extracted = ele.extracted
        let blob = `${blobAdress}/extracted-${extracted}.json`;
        const container = 'test';

        //SHOULD BE EXECUTED FOR EACH ELEMENT OF FOR LOOP
        promises.push(getTextFromBlobAsPromise(container, blob))   ;
    })

    // RUN THIS PART AFTER FOR LOOP HAS BEEN EXECUTED PROPER
    Promise.all(promises).then(dataArray => {
        console.log(dataArray) // !ASYNC JS --> DATA ARRAY IS EMPTY BECAUSE datArray IS CONSOLE.LOG BEFORE api.getText EXECTUED
    })
})
```

Comment: thx for youre answer. But when i run it, and log dataArray.length i get 3 different results ( size of req.body.array) in different orders. between 1,2,3. But i need the Array with all 3 Responses. What can i do here ?

Comment: Promise.all guarantee that response array has the same order as the promise array. So in this example you have as many concurrent requests as `req.body.array` lenght. After `.then()`, the dataArray will have all the responses.

Comment: Though, if some request will fail, the whole Promise.all() will be rejected. Then you might need `.catch(err => {})` block right after `then()`.

Comment: No, this is not normal. Make sure that `Promise.all()` is launched only once per request.

Comment: I had also a mistake in the frontend where i triggerd this function, that was responsible for all different lengths. Thx 4 youre help.